# Writing a SQL query using Min Max

Tags: sql, max, min

I have a query that provides a list of transactions by `item`, `date`, `time`, `Qty`.

```
SELECT item_no, trx_dt, trx_tm, quantity 
FROM dbo.Item_Trx_Table 
WHERE item='Item_1' AND [doc_type]<>'w' AND transDate='2016-08-22 00:00:00.000'
```

I need help figuring out how to get the `Qty` on `Min(trx_tm)` and `Max(trx_tm)` for each `Item`, and `Date`.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question makes no sense as written; you haven't provided near enough information to understand your schema or what the heck you are trying to do.

Comment: What version of SQL - SQL Server, Postgresql, MySQL, etc etc.?  Post sample DDL so we can get a full picture, bc with the current information we can not help (it would all be guesses)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you desire, but I think you want to for example get the MAX(trx_tm) for each Item, and find the Qty? If so, use GROUP BY Item and select MAX or MIN of Item or Date. Then to also get the Qty do a inner join. I would make four separate queries (MAX Item, Min Item, MAX Date, MIN Date).

Here is the first one: to get the MAX(trx_tm) for each Item, and find the Qty:

```
SELECT grp.Item, grp.max_trx_tm, tbl.Qty
(
    SELECT Item, MAX(trx_tm) AS max_trx_tm
    FROM dbo.Item_Trx_Table
    GROUP BY Item 
) AS grp
INNER JOIN dbo.Item_Trx_Table tbl ON (tbl.Item = grp.Item AND tbl.trx_tm = grp.max_trx_tm)
WHERE tbl.Item='Item_1' AND tbl.doc_type <> 'w' AND tbl.transDate='2016-08-22 00:00:00.000'
```